# Referring to .bib-file with subscript

Tags: errors, cross-referencing

I can't compile after I referred to my .bib-file with the reference:

```
title = {{Modeling O₂ transport as an integrated system limiting V(O₂MAX}},
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using the old BibTeX or `biblatex` and Biber?

Comment: If you change the subscript with `$_2$`, the subscript will be well written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematics and other special constructs need to be entered in special ways in LaTeX.  In your case, your wish to use a chemical formula, and one convenient way to enter this is via the `\ce` command of the [`mhchem` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\cite{Author:O-MAX}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

with `mybib.bib`:

```
@Article{Author:O-MAX,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Modeling \ce{O2} transport as an integrated system
                  limiting \ce{V(O2MAX)}},
  journal =  {Chem. J.},
  year =     2000
}
```

In your orignal sample, the subscripts are not standard ascii characters, and so not understood by the `bibtex` program.

Comment: I can now compile, but it reports undefined control sequence \ce, and the reference is not written with subscript - just O2.

Comment: You need the `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}` command in your main file as in the code above.